# Basic Ionic Routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a root state which is not abstract

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
     url: "/app",
     templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
     controller: 'AppCtrl'
   })
   .state('app.dashboard', {
     url: '/dashboard',
     views: {
       'landing': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
         controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
       }
     }
   });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
```

Now, my question:

- I go to url: '/app' . It works and the AppCtrl takes me to '/dashboard'
- I go to url: '/dashboard'. It works as well and the dashboard content is loaded.
- Now, I go to url : '/dashboar'. The url I now see in the address bar is '/app' but the dashboard template can be seen as well. Why is that ?? That shouldn't be the case, right ?

Comment: May you have a plunkr or anything like this?

Comment: I have put all the code here...This is basically so simple to be honest. The template is just not unloaded when I type the url incorrectly. Don't know why

Comment: What does AppCtrl look like? Does it redirect you to app.dashboard?

Comment: @Tim yes, but on the click of a button...not on load. Even if it was redirecting, it would still show me '/dashboard' url , right ?..not '/app' and still have the dashboard content loaded ?

Comment: Your router code looks fine to me, hard to say without a plunkr or codepen, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state `app.dashboard` is a child of `app` so its url is `/app/dashboard` and not `/dashboard`.

Then when you go to `/dashboar`, this url is not specified, so because of `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');` you are redirected to `/app`.

Because of the code that you are showing to us i think that you are using the side menu so its important that in `/templates/menu.html` in :

`<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
    <ion-nav-view  name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right">
    </ion-nav-view>
 </ion-pane>`

You are calling the view of `app.dashboard` "landing", so the `name` parameter of `<ion-nav-view>` should be "landing" too.

Then, if you have other states with the side menu, the view's name should be "landing" as well.

If you are not using side menu, please provide the `menu.html` content to us and the `dashboard.html` too.

Hope it helped you.